# Creating files (with password data) with JS - remove "cache"?

Tags: javascript, file, browser-cache, client-side

It's more an inquiry rather than a "problem":

I want to be able to save a CSV-file, based on data on an HTML5 page, using JS.

I found some ways to do this so that's realy not the issue.

However, after the file is downloaded by the user, it should not leave any trace in the browser and other cache, as the CSV file will contain passwords.

Is this feasable or is this done automatically?

Comment: Passwords should be encrypted using a one-way hashing algorithm, so even if you were able to put your hands on the hash somehow, you still won't be able to know what the actual password is

Comment: background: 
* my colleague gets a request of users to create. 
  She creates AD users in a certain portal.

* This portal sends a mail back to her with the user ID and initial password.

* my colleague then enters the list of users she created in our own tool ,so we can keep track, but The passwords are NOT saved in our database!

* The original requestor should however get the list of user ID's created and their initial password. the said users are then asked to change that password asap.

* The list will always be sent in a password protected ZIP file (using 7zip)

Comment: so it's more a question of HOW does the browser/JS create a file "client side" and is it stored temporarily somewhere when the "Save/Open" dialog box pops up...?
And if so, how do I remove that temporary file...?

Comment: Just done a test using code from this page:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Using Windows Search, The only file I find is the one it stores in the Download folder as it should. So I guess that's answered. 

Close as "solved" if you will...

Answer (score 0):

Just done a test using code from this page: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Using Windows Search on my entire disk, The only file I find is the one it stores in the Download folder as it should. So I guess that's answered...?

Close as "solved" if you will...